# How to access project configuration parameters from javascript in Symfony2

Tags: symfony

I'm using Symfony 2.1 dev and looking for easiest way to get parameter from app/config/parameters.yml (ini).

Simple example:

I have record in parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    url: "http://domain.com"
```

Then i want to use it somehow in static js file

```
var url = "{{ app.url }}"; // trying to avoid hardcode
```

This token should be replaced by actual value from coonfig after

```
app/console assetic:dump
```

So final js will have

```
var url = "http://domain.com";
```

Currently i'm thinking about writing my own console command but firstly i want to ensure there is no any standard way of doing such things in Symfony2 or maybe some bundle that can halp me?

UPDATE: i'd like to do this with AsseticBundle, like YUI and LESS

```
assetic:
    debug:          %kernel.debug%
    use_controller: false
    write_to:       %kernel.root_dir%/../web
    filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        lessphp: ~
        yui_js:
            jar: "%kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar"
        yui_css:
            jar: %kernel.root_dir%/Resources/java/yuicompressor-2.4.6.jar
```

to add another one filter which will replace token {{ app.url }} in js file to actual "http://domain.com"

Comment: How you want a "static" js file when your app.url is actually a variable? You should create file.js.twin and put the code in it.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to reference your parameters in the twig globals:

```
parameters:
    url: "http://domain.com"
    an_array:
        twig: "is cool"
        and: "symfony2 to"

twig:
    globals:
        app_parameters:
            url: %url%
            an_array: %an_array%
```

Then in your template:

```
<script>
window.parameters = {{ app_parameters|json_encode|raw }};
</script>
```

would render something like:

```
<script>
window.parameters = {"url":"http://domain.com","an_array":{"twig":"is cool","and":"symfony2 to"}};
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i'm currently doing, but i'd like to do this from script itself, not from twig template

Comment: yeah, this is gross.  I agree with @adrienbrault.  Ideally you should be able to create js.twig files and have the preprocessed.

Comment: The template piece should be changed to `{{ app_parameters|json_encode|raw }}`